# ng-repeat is not working in transcluded html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Please refer this code [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4oWdejmDIiqaDKLklvEs?p=preview). I am trying to build a directive which works with the transcluded html and I can't figure out why ng-repeat is not working within it. Few people also posted bugs related to this in Angular's git repo. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-simpleTranscludeExample-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="transcludeExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('transcludeExample', [])
   .directive('pane', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { title:'@' },
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                    '<div style="background-color: gray">{{title}}</div>' +
                    '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
                  '</div>'
      };
  })
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Lorem Ipsum';
    //$scope.text = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...';
    $scope.elements = ['Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...',
    'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...',
    'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...'];

  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <pane title="{{title}}">
    <li ng-repeat="element in elements">{{element}}</li>
  </pane>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open your browser console you will see an error `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]` which means you can't have duplicates in your array. You put the same string 3 times in the array that's why the repeat is not working, try with different values or change your ng-repeat to look like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="element in elements track by $index">{{element}}</li>
```

This way the elements will be tracked by their index and not by their value.

for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes